# How do you cope with the risk of false-positives in exploratory analysis?

Tags: overfitting, exploratory-data-analysis, false-positive-rate

Let's say that I'm running exploratory analysis on a dataset.
For instance, let's say that the dataset consists of several features and two groups and I want to see which features are significantly different.
I start with some modelling based on certain hypotheses and I don't find anything conclusive, then I decide to change my approach (a different model, based on different hypotheses).

I understand that there is a huge risk of false-positives every time you look at the data from another perspective. Is it enough controlling FPR by multiple testing correction?
If this procedure fails to detect differences, and I try another approach, of course, I should take into account of the previous tests, reducing more and more my statistical power.

How do usually people cope with the problem of changing their approach when doing the exploratory analysis? How do you reduce the risk of false-positives or overfitting, when looking at the data from different perspectives and you don't know what to look at (you are trying to generate hypotheses based on possible patterns)?

Comment: The concepts of "significance" (and related ones like "false positive") and "exploratory analysis" are nearly completely separate: when you explore, you develop hypotheses, you don't test.  The potential point of overlap is that when you consider a great number of hypotheses you have to downweight your hope that any one of them might be correct.  But you don't have to do this formally: a general sense of how the strength of a perceived effect must increase with the amount of exploration you do is often good enough.

Comment: Understand. Thank you! Using the language of statistical testing was a way to describing it in a formal way. Often choosing the variables that should be followed up in following experiments is based on significance tests. And my worry is that performing several of those may increase the risk of seeing a pattern in noise. I don’t know if there’s a formal way to approach EDA in general or guidelines, although I understand it’s a very challenging problem.

Comment: Many of the principles behind EDA, especially its emphasis on using *robust* and *resistant* methods, support this goal.  Reserving a final testing set or the use of more sophisticated cross-validation methods can be effective in helping you appreciate how likely any model or hypothesis might be.

Comment: Yes, I was considering CV as one of the possible tools to mitigate the risk of detecting noise patterns. Thank you very much for your help!